# python format a floating number to print .123 not 0.123

Tags: python

I have a simple question, that I feel should have a simple solution. How do I format a floating number so that only the numbers after the decimal point show? I would prefer to use '{}'.format to accomplish this.

```
>>> n = 0.12345
>>> n
0.12345
>>> str(n)[1:]
'.12345'
>>> '{}'.format(n)
'0.12345'
>>> '{}'.format(str(n)[1:])
'.12345'
```

I know I can use str(n)[1:], but I'd prefer not to have to convert the number to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a format string which removes the zero. However, you could use `lstrip`:

```
In [25]: n = 0.12345
In [26]: '{:.3f}'.format(n).lstrip('0')
Out[26]: '.123'
```

At least that is safer than `str(n)[1:]`, which would remove a signficiant digit if `n` were equal to a number bigger than 1 or less than -1.

Comment: what if I am trying to work with item = ('name',0.12345), and I was building a format string to be:'{}: {}'.(item[0],item[1])?

Comment: Well, if a preceding 0 is acceptable, then `'{}: {:.3f}'.format(*item)` works, but otherwise, you'd just have to build each piece separately:  `'{}: '.format(item[0]) + '{:.3f}'.format(item[1]).lstrip('0')`.